# Sum of two absolute values equal to a whole number

Tags: linear-algebra, absolute-value

The following is the equation:

$|x+1|+|x+2|=3$

**How can I solve this problem?**

Do I have to reformat it to $|x+1|=3-|x-2|$?

**I would like a simple answer that by no means uses set theory. The answer must include a step by step explanation**

Comment: You say not to use set theory, but bear in mind, this equation does not have one or two solutions. There will be a whole interval of solutions. It's best to express these solutions as a set, but we can also express it with an inequality if you prefer. Just a heads up.

Comment: But we can express these also with multiple inequalities @TheoBendit

Comment: Yes, that's true (and I did mention this in my comment). I was trying to confirm that you were just objecting to expressing the solution as a set, not trying to deny the fact that there is an infinite set of solutions.

Comment: @TheoBendit Oh, sorry! Didn't see that in your comment, but yea, like you said I want to just use inequalities

Comment: Did you mean $3-|x\color{red}{+}2|$ ?

Comment: @BeastCoder2: Please don't change the question to make all the answers invalid. Better to ask a new question in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You have three cases to look at:

> • Case 1: $x<-1$
>
> • Case 2: $-1\le x<2$
>
> • Case 3: $x\ge 2$

Comment: @HANDMINSOUMARE Could you please give an explanation as to how you got those cases

Comment: Look at the roots of $x+1$ and $x-2$.

Answer (score 0):

The first term $|x+1|$ is the distance from $x$ to $-1$, and the second term $|x-2|$ is the distance from $x$ to $2$. Now, considering that the points $-1$ and $2$ lie precisely $3$ steps apart on the number line, can you deduce where on the the number line $x$ must lie in order for the sum of those two distances to be $3$?

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: $x+1+x+2=3$ **>>** $x=0$

Case 2: $-(x+1)+x+2=3$ **>>** **No Solutions**

Case 3: $x+1-(x+2)=3$ **>>** **No Solutions**

Case 4: $-(x+1)-(x+2)=3$ **>>** $x=-3$

**Therefore the two answers are:**   $x=0$ and $x=-3$

> ***MAKE SURE TO CHECK THAT THE ANSWERS ARE POSSIBLE***

Comment: You seem to have mixed up $x - 2$ and $x + 2$ here.

Comment: @TheoBendit I fixed it!

Comment: Oh, so it was the original question that was wrong? The answerers will not be pleased. :-(

Comment: You should also check the feasibility of your solutions by plugging them back into the original equation. Some solutions can be false in such circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for solutions to $$|x+1|+|x+2|=3.$$

If $x<-2$ then $x+1$ and $x+2 <0$, so this means $-(x+1)-(x+2)=3,$ i.e., $x=-3.$

If $x\ge-1$ then $x+1$ and $x+2 \ge 0$, so this means $(x+1)+(x+2)=3,$ i.e., $x=0$.

If $-2\le x<-1$ then $x+1<0$ but $x+2\ge0$, so  $-(x+1)+(x+2)=3$,

which has no solution.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** if $x+1 > 0$ , $x+1 < 0$, $x+1 = 0$  and $x-2 > 0$, $x - 2 < 0$, $x-2 = 0$, etc...There are $9$ possibilities all together.

Comment: How did you get those?